# Split Cells and Push to Rows That Can Work with Blank Cells

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, with-statement, csv

I have an Excel file in which I have stored descriptions of sessions with clients, one row per session.  In one column, I have a comma-separated list that includes all the activities that happened during that session.  I have been using the following code which works well in splitting the activity list by commas, pushing each activity to a new row in another sheet, and bringing over all the other information from that row:

```
Sub SplitFoci()
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim CText As String
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim L As Integer
    Dim iColumn As Integer
    Dim lNumCols As Long
    Dim lNumRows As Long

    Set wksSource = Worksheets("OutputWorkingCopy1")
    Set wksOutput = Worksheets("OutputSplitFoci")

    iColumn = 9
    iTargetRow = 0
    With wksSource
        lNumCols = .Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).column
        lNumRows = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        For J = 3 To lNumRows
            CText = .Cells(J, iColumn).Value
            Temp = Split(CText, ",")
            For K = 0 To UBound(Temp)
                iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
                For L = 1 To 40
                    If L <> iColumn Then
                        wksOutput.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                          = .Cells(J, L)
                    Else
                        wksOutput.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                          = Temp(K)
                    End If
                Next L
            Next K
        Next J
    End With

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, if it reaches a row that has a blank cell in the activity column (i.e. an administrative task without any activities), it stops going through the list, pushing neither the administrative session information nor any client session that followed.  Does anyone know how to edit this code to allow it to push all the information and not get stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.Cells(J, iColumn).Value` has activities separated by commas, the code works well as it is split and the values from the split are enumerated through.

If `.Cells(J, iColumn).Value` has a single activity (no comma), the code works because the `Split` results in a single activity entry; e.g. both `LBound(Temp)` and `UBound(Temp)` are zero so there is a single pass through the `For ... Next` loop.

If `.Cells(J, iColumn).Value` is a blank cell (e.g. `IsEmpty(.Cells(J, iColumn) = True`), the code stops working because the `Split` results in an `LBound(Temp)` of zero and a `UBound(Temp)` of -1 and the `For ... Next` loop does not make even a single pass.

One method would be to populate Temp with a placeholder if UBound(Temp) < LBound(Temp) with something like,

```
    CText = .Cells(J, iColumn).Value
    Temp = Split(CText, ",")
    if ubound(Temp) < lbound(Temp) then Temp = Split("<non-activity>", ",")
```

This would be the same as if there was a single activity. Another method would be to make sure that at least one pass was run through the `For ... Next` loop and cover for the lack of a Temp when the time comes.

```
    For K = 0 To (UBound(Temp) - CBool(UBound(Temp) < LBound(Temp))) 'from 0 to 0 when UBound(Temp) < LBound(Temp)
        iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
        For L = 1 To 40
            If L <> iColumn Then
                wksOutput.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                  = .Cells(J, L)
            ElseIf Not CBool(UBound(Temp) < LBound(Temp)) Then
                wksOutput.Cells(iTargetRow, L) _
                  = Temp(K)
            End If
        Next L
    Next K
```

At least one pass is made through all of the columns. Column 9 is skipped altogether when there is no activity.

One of the last two code snippets should fix your loop. Choose the one that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you so much for the quick, informative, and working response!